# How to get UpdateView to work with generic FormView

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `Formview` and an `UpdateView` which are conflicting with each other. They are supposed to work together but not in this way. Whenever I try to use the `UpdateView` the values get passed through the `FormView` for saving which causes it to send back form validation errors

> e.g. 'A video with this Title already exists'.

**Forms.py**:

```
class BaseVideoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for uploading videos using related to:

    :model: 'videos.Video'.
    """
    title = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Blackjack shuffle procedures'}))
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
        help_text='A description of the content in this video.')
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        required=True)
    receiver = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=EmployeeType.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        help_text='Employees in these groups will be able to view the video.')
    video_file = forms.FileField()
    thumbnail = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description',
            'receiver',
            'category',
            'video_file',
            'thumbnail',
        )
        widgets = {
            'date_time': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'sender': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'unviewed': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'viewed': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseVideoUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['receiver'].label = "Viewers"
        self.fields['receiver'].queryset = EmployeeType.objects.all()
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.all()


class VideoUploadForm(BaseVideoUploadForm):
    send_notifications = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False,
        help_text='Send viewers a notification about the new video.')

    class Meta(BaseVideoUploadForm.Meta):
        fields = BaseVideoUploadForm.Meta.fields + ('send_notifications', )
```

**FormView:**

```
class VideoUploadView(FormView):
    form_class = VideoUploadForm
    success_url = '/videos'
    template_name = 'videos/video_form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.instance.sender = self.request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #  doing stuff

            form.save()
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
            if request.is_ajax():
                return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'url': reverse('videos-home')})
            else:
                return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            if request.is_ajax():
                return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'error': form.errors})
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**UpdateView**:

```
class VideoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Video
    form_class = VideoUploadForm
```

**Urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.VideoListView.as_view(), name='videos-home'),
    path('upload/', views.VideoUploadView.as_view(), name='videos-upload'),
    path('<int:pk>', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='videos-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', VideoDeleteView.as_view(), name='videos-delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/viewed/', views.mark_as_viewed, name='mark-as-viewed'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', VideoUpdateView.as_view(), name='videos-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/notify', VideoNotificationView.as_view(), name='videos-notify'),
]
```

How do I get the `UpdateView` to not rely on the `FormView`? Or to work with the `FormView`? It seems all the `UpdateView` is doing is pointing to the `FormView`.

Comment: a ValidationError would come from the Form, not the FormView. if you're getting validation errors then either you need to change your input or your validation rules to match your expectations.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to change my validation? I am using AJAX for form submission and the `FormView` is what is returning the response. FWIW I have been working on this for several days and cannot figure it out.

Comment: you haven't actually shared any code for the Form or the validation on it. but given the example error you posted; if you want to be able to have multiple videos with the same title, then that is a change that needs to happen on either the Video model or the VideoUploadForm class.

Comment: OK, so, how about the Video model? does Video.title have `unique=True` in its definition?

Comment: I didn't share it because I do not think it is relevant. The model has the `title` field set to `unique=True` because I do not want duplicates. This is an `UpdateView`. I am trying to *update* the model instance.